# Give display property while creating component in extjs

Tags: extjs

when creating the component:

```
 Ext.create('Ext.button', {
    text: 'Add details',
    width: 400,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'middle'
    }
 });
```

Like above bodyPadding & width, how to give display:none; property

Comment: There are 2 ways to hide component: 1. hide it completely, 2.change its visibility mode. 
Which hide you want here?

Comment: 2.change its visibility mode

Comment: Did you take a look at the [style](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#cfg-style) config?

Comment: yes @ scebotari66 it was not there

Comment: Check this link :
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.Component.html#cfg-hideMode
It tells you how to hide component.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to hide a button use the below code use `hide` function and if you required is to get the style propety get like this `btnObj.getEl().style` make sure to assign to assign button object to btnObj. for example if you put Id for your button `id: 'addBtn'` then `btnObj = Ext.getComponent('addBtn');`